# VS Code - Cannot debug blazor wasm client projetc : Unable to lauch browser "The URL's protocol must be one of ws, wss or ws+inix"

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor-webassembly

I have downloaded the Samples to accompany the official Microsoft Blazor documentation

https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples

In VS Code then I open the folder

..\blazor-samples-main\6.0\BlazorSample_WebAssembly

I let VS Code add the assets in the subfolder .vscode
launch.json
task.json

I have modified the launch.json to be

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch and Debug Standalone Blazor WebAssembly App",
        "type": "blazorwasm",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "url": "https://localhost:5001"
    }
]}
```

and I have modified the launchSettings.json located in the Properties folder to be

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57953",
      "sslPort": 44307
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "blazorwasm": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "BlazorSample": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then run the Run > Start Debugging F5 but I get the error described in the title and captured in the screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Has anyone ever encountered this problem in Visual Studio Code and knows how to fix it?
Have I missed anything or done anything wrong?
The same exact code with the blazorwasm configuration can be debugged successfully on Visual Studio 2022 but it fails as illustrated in Visual Studio Code and I do not understand why?

Some references I have used are below but I have not been able to understand the meaning of the error message below. I have tried to use Edge by switching the type in the blazorwasm but that causes Edge to crash right off the bat.

> Unable to lauch browser "The URL's protocol must be one of ws, wss or
> ws+inix"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#debug-a-standalone-blazor-webassembly-app

https://dev.to/sacantrell/vs-code-and-blazor-wasm-debug-with-hot-reload-5317

```
This is what I see on my PC


PS C:\Users> dotnet --version
7.0.102
PS C:\Users> dotnet --list-sdks
2.1.818 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.416 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.302 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.405 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: you ever find a solution to this? I've run into the same problem.

Comment: See issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45257

Comment: Thank you very much @M.Sqrl for opening the issue.

Comment: I have installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.VSCode.BlazorWasmDebuggingExtension v1.0.0.
It works. It launches the browser fine. But breakpoints in balzor client app do not work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issues. The problem was that I had older dotnet SDKs installed. After uninstalling the older versions and restarting my computer everything worked fine. :)

Comment: Hi Iliya thank you very much for posting your answer. Would you please let me know which version of the SDK is in used on your system so that I might try to remove all that I do not need and see whether it works for me, as well?

Comment: I have edited the post to show which SDKs I see present on my PC.

Comment: I use 6.0.308, but the moment that you have only one sdk version installed it should work no matter which one is it .

Answer (score 1):

blazorwasm-companion.launchDebugProxy v1.1.3 has been released today (2023-02-02) and resolves the issue.

Comment: I have tried again today from VSCode 1.76.0 and the issue seems to have been resolved. I am now able to run the Blazor Client Application in Debug Mode and it is properly launched to the Chrome browser when breakpoints are set the debugger breaks on them as expected.